# How to update values in annotation during runtime dynamically?

Tags: java, annotations

The following is a sample code:

```
@interface MyAnnotation {
String stringValue1();

String stringValue2();
}

public class Ann{
private String requireString = "str";
@MyAnnotation(stringValue1 = "abc" , stringValue2 = "")
public String getstringValue1() 
{
    return (this.requireString);
}
}
```

Here , I want to update the value of stringValue2 element of MyAnnotation atached to getStringValue() method by the value returned by "this.requireString".

Can you tell me how can this be done?

Comment: This code won't compile... (hint: `getstringValue1()` should return a boolean - not a string)

Comment: I wrote boolean mistakenly, actually, the method returns String only

Comment: And what's the benefit of the annotation in the example above ?

Comment: This annotation can be accessed from another java class in another package without hampering the depencencies

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, can you demonstrate (small example) ?

Comment: I dont have any example but I can tell u this much that this annotation will contain some key value pair kind of thing which can be scanned from another java class where I need it to fetch me the required details ( ex : MyAnnotation may contain, name and password, where password is to be provided to the annotation at runtime from a variable)

Comment: Prateek, I know what annotation does, but I don't see it in *this* case. Can you create another class and show me how you can use this annotation to reference it?

Comment: public class MainClass
{
public static void main ( String...k) {

    try {
for(Method m : Class.forName("Ann").getMethods())
 System.out.println("Annotation values for MyAnnotation are:");            
if (m.isAnnotationPresent(MyAnnotation.class)) {
 Annotation anno = m.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
                System.out.println(anno);
            }
       
} catch (Exception exc) {
    }
}
}